# Backend sub domain cookie management

Tags: nginx, cookies, nestjs, subdomain

I have my main domain `example.com`.

Subdomains:- `auth.example.com`, `app.example.com`, `www.example.com`
Backend:- `api.example.com`

Case 1 - When I server my subdomain static contents from Nginx and they make their API calls to api.example.com then NestJS (which is in `api.example.com`) is not able to set and read cookies even if cookie domain is set to `.example.com`

Case 2 - When `auth.example.com`, `app.example.com` static contents is served via NestJS like in this fashion:-

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name auth.example.com;
    location / {
    proxy_pass: http://backend ip address OR upstream address;
  }
}
```

*and NestJS serve sub-domain related static contents.*

Then NestJS is able to set and read cookies both from their subdomains and `.example.com` (global scope)

Case 2 is like working as expected, but expert says "server static content from Nginx" which I also agree. But my case 1 is not working what to do. Please Help.

I want API calls should be managed by `api.example.com` which will also balance load and subdomains related static contents should be served by Nginx.